# Loading xml file using asp.net return no records

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have this XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Option1>false</Option1>
  <Option2>http://www.google.com</Option2>
  <Option3>false</Option3>
  <Option4>false</Option4>
</configuration>
```

I trying to use code bellow to read this xml but Dataset.tables.count always return 0.

```
Dim dtConfig As New DataSet
Dim sArqXml as String = "asd.xml"

Dim xmlRoot As New XmlRootAttribute
xmlRoot.ElementName = "configuration"
xmlRoot.IsNullable = True

Dim xmlSer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(dtConfig.GetType, xmlRoot)
Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(sArqXml, FileMode.Open)

dtConfig = CType(xmlSer.Deserialize(fs), DataSet)
fs.Close()
```

How can I read this XML? The solution can be in c#.

Comment: What makes you think you can read that data into a DataSet? Did it come _from_ a DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

To load a xml file into a dataset.

```
    Imports System.Xml
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.ReadXml("path_to_your_xml_file")
```

and I think it should be ds.Table(0).Rows.Count in your case